# Using PHP to scrape image url from twitter page

Tags: php, regex, twitter, file-get-contents, scrape

I'm trying to scrape an image url from twitter e.g. 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BGZHCHwCEAACJ19.jpg:large' using php. I have found the following php code and file_get_contents is working but I don't think the regurlar expression is matching the url. Can you help debug this code? Thanks in advance.

Here is a snippet from twitter which contains the image:

```
<div class="media-gallery-image-wrapper">
     <img class="large media-slideshow-image" alt="" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BGZHCHwCEAACJ19.jpg:large" height="480" width="358">
 </div>
```

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://t.co/s54fJgrzrG';
    $twitter_page = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match('/(http:\/\/p.twimg.com\/[^:]+):/i', $twitter_page, $matches);
    $imgURL = array_pop($matches); 
    echo $imgURL;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should provide a URL.

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://t.co/s54fJgrzrG';
    $twitter_page = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match_all('!http[s]?:\/\/pbs\.twimg\.com\/[^:]+\.(jpg|png|gif)!i', $twitter_page,$matches);
    echo $img_url=$matches[0][0];
?>
```

Response is

```
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BGZHCHwCEAACJ19.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your regular expression is missing part of the beginning of the URI. It was missing the 'pbs' part, and was not able to determine if http or https.

```
preg_match('/((http|https):\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/[^:]+):/i', $twitter_page, $matches);
```